# method that repeats a loop using user input to determine number of times

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

I am having difficulty creating a a for while loop that allows the user to enter a number and that number determines how many times the loop will execute.
I need to create this method and have it execute in Main()
feeling lost and not sure why my current code isn't working.

```
 public static int InputValue(int min, int max)
        {
            //determine number of search times
            int val;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1-30:");
            val = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 0; i < val; i++)

            
            while (val > max || val < min)
            {


                Console.WriteLine("Please enter number within the range...");
                break;
            }
            
            return val;
            
        }
```

Comment: I do not understand the purpose of comparing `val` to `max` or `min`. Can you elaborate on your requirements?

Comment: There's no such thing as "a for while loop". There are `for` loops and there are `while` loops. Why are you using both? Your code makes no sense because you have a `while` loop that never executes more than once. That's called an `if` statement. Maybe you could explain what you're actually trying to achieve, rather than expecting us to work it out from code that doesn't do it.

Comment: User inputs a number between 1 and 30 and that input is used to determine how many times the loop executes. If entered number is a minus number or above 30 then user is able to re-enter. I am not sure if this answers the question I'm sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop looks intended to make sure the input number is in range.

That should happen before your `for` loop, and the line starting `val = ...` should be inside that loop. You want to break out of that "input validation" when the condition if being in range is met. I think it reads more naturally to use a `do...while` loop since the input step will happen at least once.

Finally, your `for` loop should so something useful.

Here's what all that could look like:

```
public static int InputValue(int min, int max)
{
    //determine number of search times
    int val;
    Console.WriteLine($"Enter a number between {min}-{max}:");

    do
    {
        val = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (val > max || val < min)
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter number within the range...");
    }
    while (val > max || val < min);


    for (int i = 1; i <= val; i++)
        Console.WriteLine($"Iteration {i} of {val}");


    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if input is valid beforehand. It's not very clear what you want your code to do, I think this does what you're trying to do. Also what is your for loop even for?

```
public static int InputValue(int min, int max) {
    //goes until until input is valid
    while (true) {
        int val = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (val > max || val < min) {
            Console.WriteLine($"Please enter a number between {min} and {max}");
        }
        else {
            /* does whatever once input is valid,,
            I'm not sure what you're trying to do
            with the for loop but do it in here */ 
            return val; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have in your question is effectively doing what you're asking for.

Here's a slightly cleaned up version of your code that does what you ask:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1-30:");
int val = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 0; i < val; i++)
{
    /* this runs `val` times. */
}
```

So your code is working fine as per your requirements.